# How to add a hook for post bookmark activation

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-hook

I use a bookmark based development approach and have various scripts written to help me do this.  I'd like to run one of these scripts after updating to a new bookmark.  I've added an update hook, but this seems to run before the bookmark has been changed:

```
$ hg update new-bookmark
$ <SCRIPT RUNS>
$ (activating bookmark new-bookmark)
```

How do I add a hook which will run after the current bookmark has been updated?

Answer (score 0):

Your testing just wrong. update-hooks performed [**after** new changeset become **active**](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html#sec:hook:update)

**Test-case**

```
>hg log -T "{rev}:{node|short}\n"
2:e37c7be131f2
1:ef24a87ada3d
0:a8219c43c17e
```

Hooks section of repo's .hgrc

```
[hooks]
update.UpHook = echo Update hook: && hg id -in
preupdate.preUpHook = echo PreUpdate hook: && hg id -in
```

Testing

```
>hg id -in
a8219c43c17e 0

>hg up 2
PreUpdate hook:
a8219c43c17e 0
Update hook:
e37c7be131f2 2
1 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
```

Comment: So how come the active bookmark doesn't seem to change until after the script runs?